# Why are calls auto-routing via sipDroid?

Tags: calls, sip

When sipDroid is running, everytime I try to dial a phone, it tries using sipDroid to route it. How can I make my Android using plain old GSM Network for regular calls by default when sipDroid is running?

Answer (score 4):

There's an option in the sipDroid settings (that appears automatically the first time you start it) saying whether it should be the default dialer or not. You'll need to change that setting.

Comment: In case you're not aware, you can reset this in the App manager:  From the home screen go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > SIPdroid and choose "Clear Defaults".